# Problems with drag and drop in Gtk

Tags: c, drag-and-drop, char, gtk

I'm building an application that uses drag and drop using GTK in C language but I have a problem with this part of code

```
void view_onDragDataReceived(GtkWidget *wgt, GdkDragContext *context, int x, int y,GtkSelectionData *seldata, guint info, guint time,gpointer userdata)
{
   GtkTreeModel *model;
   GtkTreeIter   iter;

    model = GTK_TREE_MODEL(userdata);

   gtk_list_store_append(GTK_LIST_STORE(model), &iter);

   gtk_list_store_set(GTK_LIST_STORE(model), &iter, COL_URI,(gchar*)seldata->data, -1);
    pathh=(char*)seldata->data;
      }
```

I call this Function from this line of code

```
 g_signal_connect(view, "drag_data_received",G_CALLBACK(view_onDragDataReceived), liststore);
```

the problem i'm having is that when i try to use that pathh variable in an other function i find it empty even though it's declared a global variable type char*

Comment: Is `pathh` a global variable? If it is, you should redesign your program, and also may be the `GtkSelectionData *seldata` is destroyed after it is passed to your function, can you print `seldata->data`?

Comment: Yeah i can print seldata and when I do the casting i can even print pathh but when i use it in an other function it is lost and it becomes empty and yes pathh is a global variable

Comment: How are you initializing `liststore`?

Comment: this is how i initialize it  'liststore = gtk_list_store_new(NUM_COLS, G_TYPE_STRING);'

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
struct SelectionData
{
    GtkListStore *listStore;
    gchar *path;
}
```

and then in the caller function

```
struct SelectionData *data;

data = malloc(sizeof(*data));
if (data == NULL)
    handleMallocFailureAndPleaseDoNotContinue();
data->listStore = liststore;
data->path      = NULL;

g_signal_connect(view, "drag_data_received",G_CALLBACK(view_onDragDataReceived), data);
```

and then

```
void view_onDragDataReceived(GtkWidget *wgt, GdkDragContext *context, int x, int y,GtkSelectionData *seldata, guint info, guint time, gpointer userdata)
{
    GtkTreeModel  *model;
    GtkTreeIter    iter;
    SelectionData *selectionData;
    size_t         length;

    selectionData = (SelectionData *)userdata;
    model = GTK_TREE_MODEL(selectionData->liststore);

    gtk_list_store_append(GTK_LIST_STORE(model), &iter);
    gtk_list_store_set(GTK_LIST_STORE(model), &iter, COL_URI,(gchar*)seldata->data, -1);
    length = strlen((char*)seldata->data);
    if (selectionData->path != NULL) /* for subsequent calls */
        free(selectionData->path);
    selectionData->path = malloc(1 + length);
    if (selectionData->path != NULL)
        memcpy(selectionData->path, seldata->data, 1 + length);
}
```

and then you can access `selectionData` somewhere else and thus it's `path` field, which must be `free`d after you finish using it.

Try to avoid global variables as much as possible.

You can also use the same technique to copy `seldata->data` into your `pathh` global variable, but rethink your design and try not to use `pathh` global variable, since you are going to use `malloc` to allocate space for the string, and the global variable will be a pointer to it, so it will be very dificult to understand where and how you must `free` it.

Comment: I'm now getting a segmentation fault :D is their a way i can send you the whole function that creates the model so you can tell me what are the changes to be done :D

Comment: @RidaAmine I am very busy right now, but you could do it later to my email iharob@gmail.com What is this project for? I see you have been working on it for a while, I think it's the same project right?

Comment: Yeah it's the same project it's just because of the exams i had to stop and now i'm resuming it's somehow an application that manages files that professor adds so that students can view them after it doesn't have the network stuff yet but i'm planning to add them later , and i'm trying to integrate the drag 'n' drop so you can easily add files :D

Comment: @RidaAmine very cool, I recieved your mail, will check it later. Is the University/Professor paying to you for this?

Comment: Wow that's quite a homework, I hope you are having fun doing it, BTW my father is Arabian, he is Syrian.

Comment: Yeah of course i'm having fun that's why i chose this field of study , it's nice that your father is Arabian even that what's happening now their is a masacre i'm from Morocco :D

Comment: @RidaAmine I was looking at your code, it's not very well formatted and it's hard to read, can you please format it? Also, remove every cast in front of the `malloc()` calls.

Comment: i sent you the new version hope it's changed a bit as i added comments :D